# Finding matching image within a collection of images using emguCV 3.1.0

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, flann

I'm working on a project to recognize (similarity percentage) a image from a collection of image. I used the EmugCV 3.1.0. The codes are given below. Although the program runs, it have following issues

1. When matches found the percentage showing always for first image. Find the attachment

[image]

2. if we put the same image in dbimage collection as twice and this same image as query image, the all matching percentage is zero. find the attachment

   string[] dbImages = { imgPath + "1.jpg", imgPath + "2.jpg", imgPath + "3.jpg", imgPath + "4.jpg" };
    string queryImage = imgPath + "4.jpg";

In these images image "2" and "4" are same

[image]

The codes are given below

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static double surfHessianThresh = 300;
        private static SURF detector;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ImageMatching();
        }

        public void ImageMatching()
        {
            string MatchString = null;
            detector = new SURF(surfHessianThresh);
            IList<IndecesMapping> matches = Match();
            IOrderedEnumerable<IndecesMapping> orderedMatches = matches.OrderByDescending(match => match.Similarity);

            foreach (IndecesMapping match in orderedMatches)
            {
                MatchString = MatchString + "\n" + match.ToString();
            }
            lblMatch.Text = MatchString;
            //Console.WriteLine();
            //Console.WriteLine("MOST LIKELY MATCH: " + orderedMatches.First());

            //Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Main method.
        /// </summary>
        static public IList<IndecesMapping> Match()
        {

            string imgPath = "E:\\Riyas\\Projects\\Image Recognition\\Sample Projects\\EmguSample3.1.0\\EmguSample3.1.0\\";
            string[] dbImages = { imgPath + "1.jpg", imgPath + "2.jpg", imgPath + "3.jpg", imgPath + "4.jpg" };
            string queryImage = imgPath + "1.jpg";

            IList<IndecesMapping> imap;

            // compute descriptors for each image
            var dbDescsList = ComputeMultipleDescriptors(dbImages, out imap);

            // concatenate all DB images descriptors into single Matrix
            Matrix<float> dbDescs = ConcatDescriptors(dbDescsList);

            // compute descriptors for the query image
            Matrix<float> queryDescriptors = ComputeSingleDescriptors(queryImage);

            FindMatches(dbDescs, queryDescriptors, ref imap);

            return imap;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Computes image descriptors.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">Image filename.</param>
        /// <returns>The descriptors for the given image.</returns>
        static public Matrix<float> ComputeSingleDescriptors(string fileName)
        {
            Matrix<float> descs = null;
            using (Image<Gray, Byte> img = new Image<Gray, byte>(fileName))
            {
                MKeyPoint[] mkeyPoints = detector.Detect(img, null);
                VectorOfKeyPoint keyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
                keyPoints.Push(mkeyPoints);

                UMat observedDescriptors = new UMat();
                detector.Compute(img, keyPoints, observedDescriptors);
                descs = new Matrix<float>(observedDescriptors.Size);
                detector.Compute(img, keyPoints, descs);
            }

            return descs;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Convenience method for computing descriptors for multiple images.
        /// On return imap is filled with structures specifying which descriptor ranges in the concatenated matrix belong to what image.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileNames">Filenames of images to process.</param>
        /// <param name="imap">List of IndecesMapping to hold descriptor ranges for each image.</param>
        /// <returns>List of descriptors for the given images.</returns>
        static public IList<Matrix<float>> ComputeMultipleDescriptors(string[] fileNames, out IList<IndecesMapping> imap)
        {
            imap = new List<IndecesMapping>();

            IList<Matrix<float>> descs = new List<Matrix<float>>();

            int r = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Length; i++)
            {
                var desc = ComputeSingleDescriptors(fileNames[i]);
                descs.Add(desc);

                imap.Add(new IndecesMapping()
                {
                    fileName = fileNames[i],
                    IndexStart = r,
                    IndexEnd = r + desc.Rows - 1
                });

                r += desc.Rows;
            }

            return descs;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Computes 'similarity' value (IndecesMapping.Similarity) for each image in the collection against our query image.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dbDescriptors">Query image descriptor.</param>
        /// <param name="queryDescriptors">Consolidated db images descriptors.</param>
        /// <param name="images">List of IndecesMapping to hold the 'similarity' value for each image in the collection.</param>
        static public void FindMatches(Matrix<float> dbDescriptors, Matrix<float> queryDescriptors, ref IList<IndecesMapping> imap)
        {
            var indices = new Matrix<int>(queryDescriptors.Rows, 2); // matrix that will contain indices of the 2-nearest neighbors found
            var dists = new Matrix<float>(queryDescriptors.Rows, 2); // matrix that will contain distances to the 2-nearest neighbors found

            // create FLANN index with 4 kd-trees and perform KNN search over it look for 2 nearest neighbours
            KdTreeIndexParamses kdparam = new KdTreeIndexParamses(4);

            var flannIndex = new Index(dbDescriptors, kdparam);
            flannIndex.KnnSearch(queryDescriptors, indices, dists, 2, 24);

            for (int i = 0; i < indices.Rows; i++)
            {
                // filter out all inadequate pairs based on distance between pairs
                if (dists.Data[i, 0] < (0.6 * dists.Data[i, 1]))
                {
                    // find image from the db to which current descriptor range belongs and increment similarity value.
                    // in the actual implementation this should be done differently as it's not very efficient for large image collections.
                    foreach (var img in imap)
                    {
                        if (img.IndexStart <= i && img.IndexEnd >= i)
                        {
                            img.Similarity++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Concatenates descriptors from different sources (images) into single matrix.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="descriptors">Descriptors to concatenate.</param>
        /// <returns>Concatenated matrix.</returns>
        static public Matrix<float> ConcatDescriptors(IList<Matrix<float>> descriptors)
        {
            int cols = descriptors[0].Cols;
            int rows = descriptors.Sum(a => a.Rows);

            float[,] concatedDescs = new float[rows, cols];

            int offset = 0;

            foreach (var descriptor in descriptors)
            {
                // append new descriptors
                Buffer.BlockCopy(descriptor.ManagedArray, 0, concatedDescs, offset, sizeof(float) * descriptor.ManagedArray.Length);
                offset += sizeof(float) * descriptor.ManagedArray.Length;
            }

            return new Matrix<float>(concatedDescs);
        }
    }

    public class IndecesMapping
    {
        public int IndexStart { get; set; }
        public int IndexEnd { get; set; }
        public int Similarity { get; set; }
        public string fileName { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return fileName + ": " + Similarity + "%";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is full solution Ahmed's Blog
http://ahmedopeyemi.com/main/face-detection-and-recognition-in-c-using-emgucv-3-0-opencv-wrapper-part-2/